# How to test an error page with Error 500 using Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, error-handling, doctrine-orm

I am working on a project where client requires me to beautifully display error 500 with stacktrace etc.
So, I checked the Error Controller and made a nice fancy error page in corresponding views/script

The problem is, how do I test it?
Whilst working on the project, I cleared error on every page and there is no way I could generate it again. Also, I am using doctrine and I remember "echo-ing" the entitymanager array but, I cannot trace the location.

How would I custom generate error 500, "keeping it real"?

PS: I tried htaccess thing and trust me, it throws apache error and not zend 500.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was pretty silly but, finally found it.

All I needed was to mis-spell a dql tablename on any page where I use querybuilder.